# What can I do once my jailbroken iPhone gets a data plan attached by AT&T?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cellular-carriers

I noticed my phone bill had a data plan attached this month to my jailbroken iPhone -- is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to talk to AT&T and have them remove the data plan, unless you're under contract for a data plan (as all new iPhones are) they should be able to take it off your next bill. Jailbreaking really doesn't have anything to do with this.